# ¿Por que no trae los datos al imput de tipo datetime-local?

Tags: javascript

Estoy pasando los datos de un registro a unos inputs cuando hago click sobre uno de los eventos, para que de esta forma se muestren en pantalla, sin embargo no pasa los datos al input de tipo datetime-local. Los campos en la abse de datos obviamente son de datetime. Estaré atento a las respuestas, gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {

$('#event_id').val(event.id);
$('#id_mot2').val(event.mot);
$('#nombre_estudiante').val(event.estudiante);
$('#jc2').val(event.jefe_c);
$('#rut_estudiante').val(event.rut_estudiante)
$('#start_f').val(moment(event.start).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'));
$('#end_f').val(moment(event.end).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'));
$('#modal_editar').modal();

},
```

Comment: No deberías aplicar el moment en start_f, también así como lo aplicas en end_f ?

Comment: Lo voy a editar, me falto el moment en el código de acá, pero tampoco funciona si esta agregado

Comment: Si no estoy mal el valor a un date se debe pasar así: 2017-10-26 por que no intentas cambiar el formar de / a -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema reside en que un `input` de tipo `datetime-local` requiere un `value` con un formato determinado. Concretamente, requiere que la fecha esté formateada en **RFC 3339**.

El formato sería el siguiente:

> YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssTO

Donde:

- **YYYY**: Año de 4 dígitos
- **MM**: Mes de 2 dígitos
- **DD**: Día de 2 dígitos
- **T**: Separador entre fecha y tiempo. Es fijo.
- **HH**: Hora en modo 24.
- **mm**: Minutos con dos dígitos
- **ss**: Segundos con dos dígitos
- **TO**: *Timezone*, o zona horaria (Z o T)

Una fecha válida sería por ejemplo:

> 2017-10-26T16:35:52Z

Comment: Excelente, gracias amigo